# ejecutar funcion script en la casilla correspondiente

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Mi duda es cuando agrego otra fila de campos cuando pongo los numeros en las casillas de la fila de abajo me toma el resultado en la fila de arriba

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<script>
 function multi(){    
                var total = 1;    
                var change= false; //    
                $(".monto").each(function(){    
                if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {    
                    change= true;    
                    total *= parseFloat($(this).val());    
                }  
            });  

            // Si se modifico el valor , retornamos la multiplicación  
            // caso contrario 0  
            total = (change)? total:0;  
            document.getElementById('Costo').value = total;  
         }  
 </script>  


 <tbody id="dataTable">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control"   name="BX_age[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <input type="text" class=" monto form-control" placeholder="Cantidad" required="required" onkeyup="multi()" name="BX_gender[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <input type="text" required="required" class=" monto form-control"  placeholder="Unitario" onkeyup="multi()" name="BX_birth[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Costo" required="required" name="BX_NAM[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control"   name="BX_ag[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" name="BX_NAM[]">
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Función que  incrementa la fila

```
function addRow(tableID) {  
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);  
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;     
    if(rowCount < 5){                           // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits  
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);   
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;  
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {  
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);   
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;   
        }   
    }else{   
         alert("Solo puedes agregar 5 productos.");  

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que necesitas es que cada fila de la tabla tenga un id único. Para esto puedes utilizar la función `elementoHTML.setAttribute('id', 'el id que quieras poner')`, de este modo:

```
function addRow(tableID) {  
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);  
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;     
    if(rowCount < 5){                           
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        row.setAttribute('id', 'row_' + rowCount);
        // ...
}
```

Los atributos `id` de html deben ser únicos, es decir no debe haber dos elementos html (sean del tipo que sean) que tengan el mismo id dentro de la misma página. 
En este caso al estar asignando id con valor `'row_' + rowCount` te garantizas que el id de la fila sea diferente dependiendo del orden en el que aparece.

Vigila esto de los ids, de todos modos, porque al copiar elementos de una fila a otra con

```
var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;  
for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {  
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);   
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;   
}
```

Estás copiando el elemento `<input>` que tienes dentro de cada una con todos sus atributos y si tienes ids en los `<input>` de la primera fila, como es el caso, los vas a estar copiando a los de la fila que insertas. Esto te puede provocar problemas después si intentas seleccionar con jquery, `getElemetById`, o `querySelector`, un elemento `<input>` concreto.

Ahora, para que `multi()` haga lo que quieres necesitas que reciba el id de la fila sobre la que tiene que operar. Por eso necesitas modificar los atributos `onKeyUp` para que manden ese id. Lo puedes hacer de esta manera:

```
<!-- ... -->
<tr id='row_2'>
    <!-- ... -->
    <td>
        <input type="text"  onkeyup="multi(this.parentNode.parentNode.id)" >
    </td>
    <!-- ... -->
</tr>
<!-- ... -->
```

Omito los otros atributos que tienes en tu código por claridad. Fíjate en que el "padre" de este input es la celda `<td>`(`this.parentNode`) y por eso tenemos que hacer `this.parentNode.parentNode` para obtener el id del "abuelo" que sería el `<tr>` que te interesa.

Ahora en la función multi() estarás recibiendo ese id como parámetro, así que la puedes modificar de esta manera, para que coja los datos de la fila que esté editando el usuario:

```
function multi(rowId){    
    var total = 1;    
    var change= false; //    
    $("#" + rowId + " .monto").each(function(){    
       //...
    });
    // ...
}
```

Pero todavía no hemos acabado porque como te decía, los ids deben ser únicos para que lo que haces en la última línea de `multi()`, cambiar el valor de la celda correspondiente al costo, realmente funcione. Podrías hacer algo parecido a lo que te explico más arriba con las filas para cambiar el id del input que te interesa cuando generas la fila, pero eso es más enrevesado cambiar el `getElementById()` por `querySelector()`. Así que yo cambiaría ese elemento input de la fila original de forma que `'Costo'` estuviera en su atributo `class` (porque `class` no necesita ser único). Así:

```
<!-- ... -->
<td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control Costo" required="required" name="BX_NAM[]"> 
</td>
<!-- ... -->
```

y entonces `multi()` quedaría de esta manera:

```
function multi(rowId){    
    var total = 1;    
    var change= false; //    
    $("#" + rowId + " .monto").each(function(){    
        if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {    
            change= true;    
            total *= parseFloat($(this).val());    
        }  
    });  

    // Si se modifico el valor , retornamos la multiplicación  
    // caso contrario 0  
    total = (change)? total:0;  
    document.querySelector('#' + rowId + ' .Costo').value = total;  
}
```

Como ves, es muy importante que tu js y html estén pensados el uno para el otro y hay que cuidar bastante como pones los atributos de los elementos html cuando pretendes trabajar con el DOM desde javascript.

Comment: Te comparto el código con  el cual  estoy generando las filas

Comment: Ok, pero no lo hagas como respuesta, edita la pregunta y ponlo ahí, para que otros usuarios que puedan tener el mismo problema lo identifiquen claramente.

Comment: Con respecto a esta linea  
  row.setAttribute(id, 'row_' + rowCount); cuando  lo  coloco  ya no  me crea la siguiente fila.

Comment: Perdona, es que es  row.setAttribute('id', 'row_' + rowCount);
Lo acabo de corregir, 'id' es el nombre del atributo que quieres añadir y por eso ha de ser una cadena de texto.

Comment: ¿Conseguiste hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: Aun no. ya me esta generando las filas pero no  veo  que los  inputs cambien de id. creo que no  entendí bien debo de quitarle los id a los inputs?

Comment: Ese row.setAttribute no cambias los ids que tienes en los inputs. Lo que debería hacer es añadir un id a los elementos <tr> de cada fila. 
Y sí, deberías quitarles los ids a los inputs porque sino te aparecerán ids duplicadas al añadir nuevas filas.

Comment: buenas tardes.   disculpa la demora de mi respuesta, si me genera los row como me comentas pero al ejecutar el multi del ejemplo que me pones, deja de funcionar la primer fila tambien, en otras palabras ya no  hace nada

Comment: Disculpa, encontré el error que estaba cometiendo. simplemente no  le había declarado el id row al primer  tr

Comment: Hola, al igual  me gustaría poder hacerte otra consulta.  sobre la ejecución de un scrip

Comment: Hola Emmanuel, si estoy conectado intentaré contestar, pero ponla como pregunta de stack overflow. Esto es un servicio a la comunidad y tu pregunta podría  servirles a otr@s

Comment: Por cierto, no postees dos veces la misma pregunta. Lo único que conseguirás es que te puntuen mal o que te las bloqueen. Si crees que no estaba claro lo que querías decir puedes editar tu pregunta, redactarla mejor y añadir más información si es necesario. De hecho, deberías leer esto si quieres que tus preguntas reciban la atención que merecen: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3761/consejos-sobre-cómo-usar-el-sitio?cb=1.

Comment: Gracias, eso para por no leer reglas antes. y la pregunta ya la abras leído antes es la que marcaste como duplicada.